# how to join date column and time column

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a date column and a time column like this:

```
Date Column "11.01.2018 00:00:00" 
Time Column: "01.01.1899 21:50:00"
```

I want to join these Date and Time to have a Result like this:

```
"11.01.2018 21:50:00"
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: your time column has the value `'01.01.1899 21:50:00'`? That's not a time, nor is it in a standardised `datetime` format. Are you storing your date, and time, values as a `varchar`? If so, you should be fixing your datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

The below converts Date and Time columns to Datetime:

```
DECLARE @MyDate   DATE = '2018-01-11'
Declare @MyTime   TIME = '1899-01-01 21:50:00'

SELECT CAST(@MyDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(@MyTime AS DATETIME);
```

Comment: Have you tried that? `SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'11.01.2018 00:00:00') + CONVERT(datetime,'01.01.18 21:50:00')` returns `2017-01-11 21:50:00.000` (wrong year).

Comment: @Larnu The poster said that the columns are Date and Time and didn't say they were held as strings.

Comment: My point under their question, however, is that their sample data clearly shows they aren't `date` and `time` datatypes columns. `01.01.1899 21:50:00` is not a time (it's a date and time). Also, if it was stored as a `datetime2(0)` then the display format would be `1899-01-01 21:50:00`. This strongly implies the OP's data isn't being stored as a `date`, `time` or `datetime(2(0))`.

Comment: But my comment here, about the wrong year, still stands. Your SQL would return the year 2017. Regardless of if data is stored as a `varchar` or `datetime(2(0))`. The year "1899" in `datetime` effectively has a value of `-1`. This means, when you add the dates together, the year expression would be `2018+(-1)` which is `2017`. And hence why the result is wrong.

Comment: @Larnu The poster was likely interpreting his own data format, implied by the double quotes. If they are storing as strings, perhaps the solution should question that?

Comment: If we don't know the datatype (the OP is yet to respond to my comment ) then the only solution would be a guess. An answer here requires too much guesswork, meaning it can (and will) be wrong, and hence why I haven't posted one. :)

Comment: @Larnu Date Column and Time Column are without brackets, so I interpret as descriptions. Please find the code working here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/21996

Comment: Because you're casting `'01.01.1899 21:50:00'` to a `time`. `'01.01.1899 21:50:00'` is not a time, it's a date and time. Times don't have years, or days, or months.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(date, @datetime1) AS DATETIME)  + CAST(CONVERT(char(10), 
@datetime2, 108) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(CONVERT(date,getdate()),' ',CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108))
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful as code with a description of how/why it solves the OP's problem.